# How do I concatenate an idxmax series with a pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I generated a pandas series of highest probability indices for a multiclass classification machine learning project using Python's idxmax function. [idxmax series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvs0Y.png) I tried to concatenate this series with my test data (after checking to see that the number of rows matched, and they do) using the code pd.concat([red_wine_test, predicted_quality], axis=1). The first item inside the square brackets is my test data and the second is the idxmax series. My code yielded the dataframe shown in the following image. [new dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfrt8.png) I am curious as to why the concatenation is not happening as intended.

Comment: Please include a small reproducible part of the code so others can try to help.

Comment: Does `pd.concat([red_wine_test.reset_index(drop=True), predicted_quality.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)` behave as expected?

Comment: The code pd.concat([red_wine_test.reset_index(drop=True), predicted_quality.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)  gets me the results I need. Thanks so much for your help!